# VSCode click from terminal pane to go to source of React compilation warnings?

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code, compiler-warnings

After saving a change to my `create-react-app` app, I got this compiler warning:

```
Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/DurationPicker.js
  Line 22:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

Is there a way to make React's warnings "clickable" so I can click on the warning in the terminal pane and the editor will navigate to the line number in the file with the warning?  (BTW I know I'm saying these are "React's warnings" but are these actually generated by ESLint?)

Old-school Visual Studio does this with compiler errors in its Output pane, which is very convenient. I'm hoping there's a similar way to do this in VS Code.

Or is there already a way to do this in VS Code, but React (or ESLint?) is not emitting its compilation warnings in the format that VS Code expects?

Comment: You can use iTerm2, works great for linting errors and failing test suites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode have a built-in mechanism to achieve what you are trying to do : [Problem matchers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher).

Also you may want to know that problem matchers works on tasks defined and launched via VSCode tasks system.

But if you want to only cach ESLint error there is an extension for that : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: Great answer. Exactly the info I was looking for. Thanks!